# JavaScript Var handling inside function

Tags: javascript, jquery, var

My Code:

```
$("img.rollover-neu").hover (
        function() { 
            var org_src = $(this).attr('src');
            this.src = $(this).attr("data-rolloverImage"); }, 
        function() { alert("h"+org_src); /*this.src = $(this).attr('src', org_src);*/ } 
    );
```

On Mouse-enter i save the src of an image inside a var "org_src". On Mouse-Out it should change the src back. Unfortunately the var "org_src" is empty at the mouse-out function. Any help why?

Thanks

Comment: `org_src` is only scoped to the first function, but not the second.

Comment: Why not assign it to a data attribute so you can use it on mouse out too.  Or just make the org_src global.  Also for data attributes, you can use `$(this).data("rolloverImage");`

Answer (score 1):

Why not pull the `org_src` variable out of your event handlers?

```
var org_src
$("img.rollover-neu").hover(function() { 
    org_src = this.src
    this.src = this.getAttribute("data-rolloverImage")
}, function() {
    this.src = org_src
});
```

Comment: Thanks! You save my day!

Answer (score 0):

using var you org_src is local to that function, you can create a global variable or use a attribute to store your data

```
$("img.rollover-neu").hover (
        function() { 
            var org_src = $(this).attr('src');
            $(this).attr('org-src',org_src);
            this.src = $(this).attr("data-rolloverImage"); 
        }, 
        function() { 
           var org_src = $(this).attr('org-src');
           this.src = $(this).attr('src', org_src);
       } 
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you delcare a variable within a function, it is scoped to that function - have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript) for a good explanation of scoping

In your case I would use a data attribute to store your original source so you can just reuse it on the mouseout:

```js
$("img.rollover-neu").hover(
  function() {
    var image = $(this);
    image.data('org-src', this.src);
    this.src = image.data("rolloverImage");
  },
  function() {
    this.src = $(this).data('org-src');
  }
);
```